# How to rotate and translate elements of an 3D array? Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

My question is:

How to implement output array(A1) by rotate and translate elements(first and second cube) of an 3D Array(A0)?

A0 - input array
A1 - output array

Here is my code:

```
%Create Array 3D uint8 format, A0
A0 = zeros(100,100,40,'uint8');
%First cube
A0(5:45, 5:45,3:17) = 1;
%Second Cube
A0(55:95,55:95,23:37)=1;
```

I try:

```
Y = circshift(A0,[1 1])
```

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have an affine transformation matrix? Are you applying the same transformation to both cubes, or different ones?

Comment: I am tried only a rotation for array...

May be the same or different to both cubes.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you've tried, and describe how your code fails to do what you want.

Comment: Ok, I edited code.

Comment: That doesn't seem like an affine transformation to me. What rotation/translation are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It can be rotated by a few degrees

Comment: You should define exactly what you want. Alpah degrees of rotation along the z axis beta dgrees of rotation along the x axis .... N pixels of translation along the x-axis M pixels ... And than use http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/affine3d-class.html to create your afffine transformation and http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imwarp.html to apply it.